# How to implement Flutter Riverpod FutureProvider with shared_preferences library?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, state, persistence, riverpod

My current implementation without FutureProvider + shared_preferences:

```
class IdentityModel {
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  final int id;
  final String userName;
  final String avatarUrl;

  const IdentityModel({
    this.isLoggedIn = false,
    this.id,
    this.userName,
    this.avatarUrl,
  });
}

class IdentityNotifier extends StateNotifier<IdentityModel> {
  IdentityNotifier() : super(_initialState);

  static final _initialState = IdentityModel();

  void loginAction(MyCustomUserClass user) {
    state = IdentityModel(
      isLoggedIn: true,
      id: user.id,
      userName: user.userName,
      avatarUrl: user.avatarUrl,
    );
  }

  void logoutAction() {
    state = IdentityModel(
      isLoggedIn: false,
      id: null,
      userName: null,
      avatarUrl: null,
    );
  }
}

final identityProvider = StateNotifierProvider<IdentityNotifier>(
  (ref) => IdentityNotifier(),
);
```

I want to persist state using the `shared_preferences` package, but I'm not quite sure how to convert my current implementation to one that uses `FutureProvider` as `shared_preferences` uses `async/await` to get/set.

I basically want to "load" from `shared_preferences` using it's `get` methods to initialize the notifier when the app starts up and then call `shared_preferences` `set` methods in the notifier methods `loginAction` and `logoutAction`.

Comment: You can use hydrated_bloc that will save your bloc states https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc

Comment: @Ayad That package is only for bloc? Does it work with riverpod?

Comment: It's only for bloc I don't think there is a package that uses riverpod.

Comment: watch this video link below ,on 17:20 - 20:00 we can use dependency overrides and combining provider to avoid await to get shared preferences instance over and over again then combine it to other provider https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2iFYZUabVM

Answer (score 0):

if your IdentityNotifier depend from a Future it should be a StateNotifier<AsyncValue> this allow you to show differents info on the UI if the future isn't yet loaded or has an error.

```
class IdentityNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<IdentityModel>> {
  IdentityNotifier({this.prefs}) : super(AsyncLoading());
  final SharedPreferences prefs;

  void init() {
    /// check user & get state from prefs
    state = AsyncData(IdentityModel(id:prefs.getInt("id")));
  }

  void loginAction(MyCustomUserClass user) {
    /// set info in prefs
    state = AsyncData(IdentityModel(
      isLoggedIn: true,
      id: user.id,
      userName: user.userName,
      avatarUrl: user.avatarUrl,
    ));
  }

  void logoutAction() {
    /// set info in prefs
    state = AsyncData(IdentityModel(
      isLoggedIn: false,
      id: null,
      userName: null,
      avatarUrl: null,
    ));
  }
}
```

to make your provider depend from the future provider :

```
final identityProvider = StateNotifierProvider<IdentityNotifier>((ref) {
  
  return ref.watch(_sharedPref).when(
      data: (prefs){
        final identityNotifier =  IdentityNotifier(prefs: prefs);
        identityNotifier.init();
        return identityNotifier;
      },
      loading: () => IdentityNotifier(),
      error: (_, __) => throw "error" /// throw or set an error state in your notifier
      );
  
});

final FutureProvider<SharedPreferences> _sharedPref =
    FutureProvider((ref) async => SharedPreferences.getInstance());
```

first frames your IDNotifier will be loading you can display CircularIndicator...
next when sharedPref instance is loaded IdNotifier is re-instancied with the pref reference and the init methods set your user data